# Go App Engine get version in init() without Context

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is there a way to to get my autoscaled application's VersionID in my `init()` function without a `Context`? The only available option seems to be `appengine.VersionID(context.Context)`. Manually scaled instances have `/_ah/start` called when they start up (giving access to a `Context`), but there is nothing like this for autoscaled instances.

I am not caring about the generated ID that `appengine.VersionID` returns with it, just the app.yaml version.

EDIT: A bit of context: I am wanting to deploy versions in the form x-x-x-dev or x-x-x-live and have my database connection depend on the version suffix. This way, when I look in the GCP console, I can be certain which deployed modules/services are using which database. Of course, I setup my DB connection pool in the `init()`, which has no access to a `Context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and searched with no answers online anywhere, so here it is.

Simply parse the app.yaml file in your `init()` function. My example here uses a yaml parsing package, but it can be done more lightweight if you need.

```
import "github.com/ghodss/yaml"

type AppVersion struct {
    Version string `json:"version"`
}

func VersionID() (string, error) {
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("app.yaml")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    a := &AppVersion{}
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(dat, a)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return a.Version, nil
}
```

Note that this DOES NOT return the generated ID in the form X.Y that [`appengine.VersionID()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#VersionID) does. Only the X part of the version.

As an aside, in the appengine repo on Github, the actual call to `appengine.VersionID` requires a `Context`, but internally calls the internal package with `nil`. So they basically force you to call it with a `Context`, but it isn't actually used. It's incredibly infuriating.

EDIT: It should be noted that the new Go SDK in gcloud no longer supports `version` in the app.yaml, as it is now a required parameter at deploy. However, the "legacy" SDK is still supported and maintained, which I am continuing to use as of today (12/24/2018).